# Databinding and INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, inotifypropertychanged

In my WP7 app I want to update the ApplicationTitle string on all pages at the same time, when something is changed. I've searched for ways of doing it, and people talk about using databinding and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. However, using the samples i've found, I cannot make it work. I suspect the binding to be wrong, but haven't been able to spot the error.

I have a class called "RegistrationQueue" which has the following code:

```
    public void Gem()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        if (settings.Contains("regqueue"))
        {
            settings["regqueue"] = _registreringsListe;
        }
        else
            settings.Add("regqueue", _registreringsListe);

        AppTitle = "LOGIMATIC A/S - " + _registreringsListe.Count + " registreringer i kø";
    }
```

And this:

```
    private string _AppTitle;

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the property that will be the source of the binding.
    public string AppTitle
    {
        get { return _AppTitle; }
        set
        {
            _AppTitle = value;
            // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
            // is updated.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AppTitle");
        }
    }


    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event, 
    // passing the source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Which is basicly a copy/paste from MSDN as far as I can remember.

In one of my XAML pages I've written this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="{Binding AppTitle, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
```

And I thought it would work, but it does not. What am I doing wrong here?

Full XAML for the page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="FotoDokUdkast.loginScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <!--<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="LOGIMATIC A/S" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>-->
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="{Binding Path=AppTitle, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="FotoDok 0.5b " Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Background="Black">
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Et Logimatic program" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" />
            <toolkit:ListPicker Name="pickerProject" Margin="9,42,15,0" Header="Vælg projekt" ListPickerMode="Normal" ItemCountThreshold="0" FullModeHeader="Vælg projekt" Height="97" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Button Content="Log ind" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,337,0,0" Name="btnLogin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" Click="btnLogin_Click" />
            <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Vælg bruger" Margin="9,145,15,292" Name="pickerUser" ListPickerMode="Normal" ItemCountThreshold="0" FullModeHeader="Vælg bruger" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar.sync.rest.png" Text="Opdater projekter" Click="ApplicationBarIconButtonOpdater_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar.delete.rest.png" Text="Slet projekter" Click="ApplicationBarIconButtonSlet_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar.feature.email.rest.png" Text="Registreringer i kø" Click="ApplicationBarIconButtonRegistrering_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar.feature.settings.rest.png" Text="Tilpas opsætning" Click="ApplicationBarIconButtonSettings_Click"/>

        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I've then written "DataContext = "RegistreringsKø"; " in the constructor for the XAML page (loginscreen.cs)

Comment: Does it work on first run, but not when you change the title, or does it never work?

Comment: As I've said further down.. we need to see more of the XAML structure if the correct datacontext is being set in the ctor (and isn't null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with what you have posted so far.  My guess would be that the `DataContext` current for where the `TextBlock` is sited is not an instance of the class that has this `AppTitle` property.  Hence the binding doesn't work not because it can't find the `AppTitle` property.

Answer (score 1):

Stating the obvious, but it's bitten me before, are you sure the class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and doesn't just have the event declared?

I've been bitten by that in the past when removing a view model base class .. took me ages to figure it out :-)

Failing that - anything binding errors showing up in the Output window when you're debugging?

Comment: The RegistrationQueue class does implement the interface, if only that was the problem :)

Comment: i just checked the output window, and actually it does post an error:

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'AppTitle' property not found on 'RegistreringsKø' 'System.String' (HashCode=-1626748841). BindingExpression: Path='AppTitle' DataItem='RegistreringsKø' (HashCode=-1626748841); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='ApplicationTitle'); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..

Comment: Your DataContext is wrong then by the looks of it - it's set to an instance of RegistreringsKø, which doesn't have that property on it.

Comment: In the constructor for the page, `DataContext = foo;` where `foo` is the object that has `AppTitle` as a property.

Comment: I assume foo isn't null? :-) Is that block of xaml you've pasted inside a listbox or anything? If the whole xaml file isn't too big it might be useful to see the whole lot.

Comment: Okay, here's the XAML for a page I want to use the AppTitle (updated my question at the top).

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the Datacontext correctly.
I had written `ApplicationTitle.Text = "RegistreringsKø"`
Which of course should've been an instance of the object instead.

So in my case, `DataContext = Registration.getInstance();` solved it.